# Flash fill possible in R?

Tags: r

How would flash filling based on observation data that is tied to another column look for R?
Example

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
                   B = c('my initials1', NA, NA, NA,NA,'my initials2',NA,NA))
```

Is there a way to have my initials (which are tied to 1) fill down?
I've tried

```
df |> fill(B)
```

But what happens is it fills down to the next observation in B. Where I'd like the fill to stop at the end of 1 based on column A instead.
I was just thinking of copying the data to a separate data frame and joining it on A to achieve that.

Comment: Check the fill function from package tidyr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(A) %>%
   mutate(B = first(B[!is.na(B)])) %>%
   ungroup
# A tibble: 8 × 2
      A B           
  <dbl> <chr>       
1     1 my initials1
2     1 my initials1
3     1 my initials1
4     1 my initials1
5     2 my initials2
6     2 my initials2
7     2 my initials2
8     2 my initials2
```

Comment: Group by is the key

Comment: To add for those coming here later. `fill` needs you to specify columns. If you want to fill EVERY column in your df, then you can use this `df <- df %>% fill(names(df), .direction = "down")`. Don't forget to group as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by the first column, then it will only fill down within the group:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  fill(B, .direction = "down")
```

**Output**

```
      A B           
  <dbl> <chr>       
1     1 my initials1
2     1 my initials1
3     1 my initials1
4     1 my initials1
5     2 NA          
6     2 my initials2
7     2 my initials2
8     2 my initials2
```

Or if you want to fill in for every group, then you can change the `.direction` argument:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  fill(B, .direction = "updown")
```

*Output*

```
      A B           
  <dbl> <chr>       
1     1 my initials1
2     1 my initials1
3     1 my initials1
4     1 my initials1
5     2 my initials2
6     2 my initials2
7     2 my initials2
8     2 my initials2
```